# About the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)\,dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)}}$ and related hypergeometric functions

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I will be honest about it: the following integral is involved in my current investigations about the interplay between Fourier-Legendre series expansions, hypergeometric functions of the $\phantom{}_3 F_2$ and $\phantom{}_4 F_3$ kind and polylogarithms. Significative contributions will be rewarded through a proper mention of the author.

The value of $\phantom{}_3 F_2\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{4},1;\tfrac{5}{4},\tfrac{3}{2};-1\right)$ is related to the integral 
$$ \mathcal{J}_1 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)}}\,dx, $$
which on its turn (by Feynman's trick) is related to 
$$ \mathcal{J}_2 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},1;\frac{1}{4};-x^2\right)}{x^2}\,dx.$$
I would be glad to know how to convert $\mathcal{J}_1$ (or $\mathcal{J}_2$) into a combination of standard mathematical constants and polylogarithms. It most certainly *can* be done since $\arctan(x)=\text{Im}\log(1+ix)$, but my version of Mathematica is not collaborating with me as I wished.

I will be away from keyboard for a few days (time to work for the Italian most celebrated mathematical contest), I hope to find some nice insight after my return.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. $$ \mathcal{J}_1 = \tfrac{1}{16}\,\sqrt{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2 $$ by a nasty symmetry trick, which, as usual, is not recognized by Mathematica. I do not spoil the steps of my solution since you might have some fun with this problem.

Comment: My friend sure did :D